# Insert only if timestamp is unoccupied

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am using Android / Java and SQLite3 / SQLiteOpenHelper, with the Cursors and ContentValues.

I have a timestamp field in my table. I want to ensure that if someone is adding a new row, the row is not added if the timestamp is already occupied (so I do not want more than one value per timestamp).

Can this be enforced efficiently? Or do I have to perform a select statement every single time I perform an insertion to check first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE` qualifier on the timestamp field. You can then choose the behavior you want by calling [`inserWithOnConflict()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) and passing `CONFLICT_FAIL` as the conflict algorithm argument.

Comment: Does this mean any inserts that have the same timestamps are simply ignored or do they throw an error, etc?

Comment: Take a look at the javadocs I linked. You can choose the behavior you want. `CONFLICT_FAIL` will cause an exception to be thrown,

Comment: Oh sorry the post had been edited. I see it now. Thanks! Can accept in 5.